# DBeaver : change default settings for Find/Replace window

Tags: dbeaver

Using DBeaver as regular SQL-tool.
Working with SQL stored procedures, which are ETL legacy code.
Due to this regularly is required to search some text "from bottom to top" of SQL code.

Every time on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>(Find dialog) in DBeaver I need to change search direction: from Forward(default setting) to Backward - see screenshot below.

After closing Find/Replace window DBeaver forgets my choice and opens it with default settings (Forward) on next <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

If someone knows, let me know how to deal with it?
How to change default setting to Backward?

[image]